# How to solve Non-resolvable import POM?

Tags: maven, docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, s4sdk

This is the error i am facing while doing a Jenkins build by pulling a maven project from GitHub.

> ```
> [ERROR] Non-resolvable import POM: Could not transfer artifact
> com.sap.cloud.s4hana:sdk-bom:pom:1.4.0-SNAPSHOT from/to nexus-central
> (http://<nexus server>/nexus/content/groups/build.snapshots/):
> <nexus server> @ line 16, column 25
> ```

I am currently working on `VMware workstation 14` player for `Linux` and using Jenkins image from Docker to run this build.

Below is error image

[image: Error image]

Comment: So can you connect _http://nexus.wdf.sap.corp:8081_? It says **name** does not resolve.

Comment: This URL is opening on my system.

Comment: But seems that not in Jenkins? _unknown host nexus.wdf.sap.corp_

Comment: i did not get you

Comment: Your image has at line 13 _unknown host nexus.wdf.sap.corp_, where does this script run?

Comment: It is in the settings.xml file in Maven repository

Comment: Could you try to test whether the host 'nexus.wdf.sap.corp' is reachable from the server where your Jenkins is running on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You specified a custom maven settings.xml in your project, which specifies a custom nexus server as maven central mirror. However, at runtime the pipeline fails to connect to this server.

Could it be that your intranet nexus is not available from within your Cx Server container? Please check that you use proper network settings (e.g. that your corporate proxy is properly configured).

Furthermore, the comments regarding the SNAPSHOT version are correct too - please only use released versions of the SDK (currently 1.4.0).

Answer (score 0):

> I am currently working on VMware workstation 14 player for Linux and
>   using Jenkins image from Docker to run this build.]

You say you can access `nexus.wdf.sap.corp` from your local machine, but can your Docker image do the same? It seems not: `com.sap.cloud.s4hana: Name does not resolve`

Be aware your Docker image may not share the same network configuration than your host. You may want to use the [--add-host flag](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#managing-etchosts) when running your Jenkins image so it can resolve your site.

Comment: what would be the  --add-host flag i should use?

Answer (score 0):

Please either remove the -SNAPSHOT from your SDK BOM or use 1.5.0-SNAPSHOT or 1.5.1-SNAPSHOT. There is no 1.4.0-SNAPSHOT version anymore, just the released 1.4.0 version.

The latest released version is 1.5.0 (non SNAPSHOT).